# how can i get the PortletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

My problem is to obtain `PortletRequest` from `HttpServletRequest`

I put this sentence:

```
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) HttpServletRequest.getAttribute();
```

What should I put into the `.getAttribute();`

When I developed in IBM Portlet Factory, I used `.getAttribute(Constants.PORTLET_REQUEST)`
The Constants are into one `.jar`

Now I need to do this with `Portlet` in `JSR168` or there is another way to obtain `PortletRequest` without using `HttpServletRequest`

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
(PortletRequest) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.request");
(PortletResponse) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.response");
```

Request and response are of `HTTPServletRequest` and `HTTPSevletResponse`.

Comment: I added this code in post login hook getting value null

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're programming a servlet since you have a HttpServletRequest and no PortletRequest. Which means you won't have a PortletRequest. You'll need to be programming portlets to get PortletRequests and in that case, the API interfaces and portlet container provide the PortletRequest.

I don't know how the internals of Portlet Factory worked that you would need to obtain a PortletRequest like that but that's not typical portlet programming.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are making a JSR 168 portlet.

In that case your portlet class should be implementing `javax.portlet.Portlet`

To implement that interface you implement:

`render(RenderRequest, RenderResponse)`

and

`processAction(ActionRequest, ActionResponse)`

These are called by the portlet container when it decides to render your portlet or handle a user action from your portlet.

The request objects `RenderRequest` and `ActionRequest` are `PortletRequest`s.  So you get it directly as an argument, you don't have to query something for it.

Comment: Ok i now that the parent from RenderRequest and ActionRequest are PortletRequest but how i get it.
ActionRequest arequest = new ActionRequest();
Just like that?

Comment: It is passed in as the first argument to your `processAction` method, which is called by the portlet container (you don't call this method).